# Upload multiple files from Client to Server via API using HTTP guzzle in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I tested by postman to attach file with field fileupload[0](see screenshot below) that works fine, request is added and `fileupload` also uploaded to server.

But I want to call that upload file api by my laravel HTTP Client

I have tried below code

```
$result = Http::attach(
            'attachment', $request->fileupload
        )->asForm()->post('http://192.168.1.100/api/request/store', $form_param);
```

my control in form upload:

```
 <input type="file" name="fileupload[]" multiple>
```

[image: postman screenshot]

But it seem like API server  does not get my request file from the client side.

So how to upload file(or multiple files) via client using laravel HTTP?

Comment: this `$request->fileupload` should be `$request->file('fileupload')` if there is one file but I guess you are uploading multiple files

Comment: @bhucho yes i upload multiple file do u have solution

Answer (score 2):

There are few things you need to change.

This is a line written in documentation of guzzle. As Http Client is the wrapper class of guzzle it applies on it as well.

> multipart cannot be used with the form_params option. You will need to use one or the other. Use form_params for application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for multipart/form-data requests.

Also as you shown in your screenshot of postman above as well, that you are content-type of your data is `form-data` not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So you cannot use `asForm()`. It internally sets content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The **attach()** function internally adds `asMultipart()` so you don't need to add it.

Secondly,  In order to pass multiple attachment you need to pass array as first argument to the attach() function. For that

```
    if($request->hasFile('fileupload')) {
        $names = [];
        foreach ($request->file('fileupload') as $file) {
            if(file_exists($file)){
                $name= $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $names[] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now pass this array `$names` to the attach method,

```
$result = Http::attach(
            $names, $request->file('fileupload')
        )->post('http://192.168.1.100/api/request/store', $form_param);
```

If you pass array as first argument internally this function is recursive and calls itself to upload all files.

---

Though it is not part of question but I recommend calling http requests in the given format below.

> ```
>    try{
>    $result = Http::attach(
>             $names, $request->file('fileupload')
>         )->post('http://192.168.1.100/api/request/store', $form_param);
>    $result->throw(); 
> } catch(\Illuminate\Http\Client\RequestException $e){
>    \Log::info($e->getMessage());
>    // handle your exception accordingly
> }
> ```

As it is never a guarantee that the response will always be ok.

Comment: So I followed your answer, but I get the error: "Only arrays and Traversables can be unpacked" on $names after the attach. With dd($names) I checked if $names really is an array and if it contains the right data, which it is and it does contain an array of the file names. Do you have any idea what might be going wrong here?

Comment: may be in some conditions if you are using some loop it might be sending null for no file found, you can put a check `is_array()`

Comment: I've added an IF statement around the $result, but it still passes so it has to be an array. I've also created a question here on StackOverflow with the full code and stacktrace, I would appreciate it if you can take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897044/only-arrays-and-traversables-can-be-unpacked-error-with-a-guzzle-http-post-reque